# How to skip loading file if it is already loaded in memory using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, environment-variables, global-variables

I have the following code where I am trying to avoid loading `symspell.pkl` file once it is already loaded in memory:

```
from symspellpy import SymSpell

if 'sym_spell' in globals():
    print('sym_spell is already loaded!')
    sym_spell = global()['sym_spell']
esle:
    print('loading sym_spell...')
    sym_spell = SymSpell(max_dictionary_edit_distance=5, prefix_length=7)
    sym_spell.load_pickle('symspell.pkl')
```

but it seems python always executing the `else` statement even if the `if` statement is `True`.

Following are my questions:

- Can anyone explains why Python is always executing `else` statement here?
- Is what I tried a right way to skip loading file if it is already loaded in memory in Python? If not, is there a better way?

I am using python3.8.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my fix  just in case it might be helpful.

After many attempts, I got it worked using `builtins` module (instead of `globals()`)
and `try/except` statement like the following:

```
import builtins
from symspellpy import SymSpell    

try:
    if builtins.sym_spell:
        print('sym_spell is already loaded!')
        sym_spell = builtins.sym_spell
except:
    print('sym_spell is not yet loaded! loading sym_spell...')
    sym_spell = SymSpell(max_dictionary_edit_distance=5, prefix_length=7)
    sym_spell.load_pickle('symspell.pkl')
    builtins.sym_spell = sym_spell
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what you are trying to do but that `if` statement is always False because  there is no "sym_spell" in globals. I think you are trying to check "SymSpell" rather then "sym_spell".

**Edit :**

> Is what I tried a right way to skip loading file if it is already loaded in memory in Python? If not, is there a better way?

No I don't think if there is a way to do what are exactly asking. But if your file is very huge and you don't want to load that same data again and again and again. Then, this is the best solution for you. Yoi can look at the [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyter.org/) or [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/).
**Jupyter Lab :**

> JupyterLab: Jupyter’s Next-Generation Notebook Interface
> JupyterLab is a web-based interactive development environment for Jupyter notebooks, code, and data. JupyterLab is flexible: configure and arrange the user interface to support a wide range of workflows in data science, scientific computing, and machine learning. JupyterLab is extensible and modular: write plugins that add new components and integrate with existing ones.

**Jupyter Notebook :**

> The Jupyter Notebook is an open-source web application that allows you to create and share documents that contain live code, equations, visualizations and narrative text. Uses include: data cleaning and transformation, numerical simulation, statistical modeling, data visualization, machine learning, and much more.

Here you can load your data one time, and without importing that data you can use multiple times. You can test it now from your browser directly, to see how it is. From there [official website](https://jupyter.org/). I think this would be very useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am really checking `sym_spell` and as I stated the `if` statement is True.

Comment: Sorry, but  what I mean is it didn't answer my question.

Comment: I didn't exactly understand your question. Please elaborate with example if possible!

Comment: Isn't _it seems python always executing the else statement even if the if statement is True_ your question? And haven't my solution solved your issue?

Comment: Ok. The very first time I run my script,  `sym_spell in globals()`  == False and it executes the `else` statement. When I run for the second time `sym_spell in globals()`  == True, and it should execute the `else` statement.

Comment: I will update my answer stay connected!  You aren't running provided code in loop, right? You are just running that code normally mean, `python <file.py>` every time, right?

Comment: @R.Marolahy I have updated the answer. Check it!

Comment: Yes using `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter lab` can do the job, but I think  it's not a better way in may case. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Why you think that? I think it is better because it stores your data. And you can use anytime!